# Office drones want wireless mice. How can I avoid interference?

Tags: bluetooth, interference

There were a handful of mice bought before I got here and they've had bad issues with random clicks, movements, and pauses. They've also had some issues getting them synced. They're using 27MHz RF.

So, I could use Bluetooth, but there's already a preponderance of headsets running around. What are the chances we'll get interference with them?

Who has experience with this?

Comment: Can you tell us what brand these are?  I'm running wireless Microsoft Mice and don't have a lick of trouble, so I'm curious what brand you're using....

Comment: Bofh answer: give 27mhz mice, buy jammer on said frequency. Practice the way you deliver "I told you so"

Comment: They're HP mice. Product number: VK479AA

Comment: "Office Drones" sounds very condescending...

Comment: It might be condescending, but no one here is your typical office worker. It's absurd enough to be a joke.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

**Rant:**

27MHz wireless keyboards and mice are a huge support hassle due to short range and interference.  They are also extremely insecure.  I would not even allow them on the premises.

**Answer:**

Bluetooth devices are designed not to interfere with each other.  Because Bluetooth is low-power/low-range and it uses [frequency-hopping spread-spectrum](http://www.swedetrack.com/images/bluet11.htm) communications, you do not need to worry about cross-interference between headsets and keyboards/mice.

Of course, there are other potential sources of interference in the 2.4 GHz spectrum: cordless phones, microwave ovens, WiFi, etc.  However, if your end-users are already using Bluetooth headsets without issues, you are very unlikely experience any new problems when you add Bluetooth keyboards and mice.

**Additional advice:**

The only support calls that you are likely to get for Bluetooth keyboards and mice will pertain to dead batteries.  ("My computer froze!  The mouse won't even move!")  These too can be prevented: at the *same time* as you purchase the wireless keyboards/mice, get a high-quality [NimH battery charger](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B000RSOV50) (La Crosse is fantastic) and [rechargeable AA batteries](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B000LNI5VC) (must be ULSD, Sanyo Eneloops are best).  **Create a schedule** so that each wireless mouse/keyboard user gets **batteries replaced and recharged on a predictable, routine basis**, before they go dead.  It will save time and frustration in the long run.

Otherwise, wireless mice/keyboards have a real cost to your organization in terms of urgent support calls and lost end-user productivity every time the batteries "unexpectedly" run out.

Comment: +1, You don't need to worry unless there's a lot of them in *really close* proximity. I'd be much more worried about someone with a 80.211n network in the area; those things are spectrum hogs.

Comment: Funny you should mention that. There is a 802.11n network in the area.

Comment: With the 802.11n networks, it depends a lot on the details.  Junk-grade consumer 802.11n devices can be serious RF jammers, but standards-compliant WiFi devices [must be engineered to be Bluetooth-friendly](http://www.eetasia.com/ART_8800472104_590626_NT_d754e395.HTM).  If your headset users aren't having a problem, I wouldn't worry about it.

Comment: Yeah, I remember stories when the 802.11n-draft devices were first coming out that they worked better at jamming everyone elses signals than giving you a working connection.

Comment: There are bluetooth mice that come with charging stations.

Comment: That's also a valid option, although I cannot say with confidence that I would trust end-users to actually use them.

Comment: Of course, your population of end-users may be more tech-savvy than ours.